# Getting completely wrong fit from python scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

Update: solved!
It is producing parameters with the correct signs now, and they do fit the curve. The problem was defining func(a,b,c,x) but curve_fit needs to read x first: func(x,a,b,c). Thanks everyone for all the help! I'll have quantitative analysis when I meet with my boss today :)

Here's some of the new fits: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8idj0.jpg

(I still get a run-time error:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
return a*(math.e**(b*(math.e**(c*x))))
```

)

---

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with this code? I am new to scipy.
I am trying to model bacterial growth with the [Gompertz equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function), but my code produces a curve_fit that's completely wrong. You can see images of my real data, the model equation, and the fit this code produces in [this imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKPb8.jpg)
Thanks!

---

Fixed code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

values = numpy.asarray(values)  
y = values[:2000//5].astype(numpy.float)
y - y[0] #subtracting blank value
x = numpy.arange(len(y))*5

def Function(x,a,b,c):
  #a = upper asymptote
  #b = negative = x axis displacement
  #c = negative = growth rate
  return a*(math.e**(b*(math.e**(c*x))))

parameters, pcov = curve_fit(Function, x, y, p0=[0.1,-1300,-0.0077])

#Graph data and fit to compare
yaj = Function(  numpy.asarray(x), parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2] )
figure(1, figsize=(8.5,11))
subplot(211)
plot(x,y,'g-')
xlim(min(x),max(x))
ylim(min(y),max(y))
subplot(212)
plot(x,yaj,'r-')
xlim(min(x),max(x))
ylim(min(yaj),max(yaj))
savefig('tempgraph.pdf')

return parameters
```

Comment: It's a non-linear solver, so it's inherently sensitive to the initial guess. Have you tried making a better inital guess?  Also, if your model parameters vary by more than a couple of orders of magnitude (e.g. `a=0.0001, b=-20, c=40000000`), then you'll need to normalize things. Otherwise, calculating the jacobian through finite differences will be very inaccurate, and the solution won't converge properly.  Also, if you can post a sample of your data somewhere (e.g. pastebin, etc) it would help diagnose problems (maybe every 100th sample, or something similar, if it's very large).

Comment: How do I make an initial guess? As it is, a, b, and c are undefined. The model parameters _should_ all be the same order of magnitude. Their signs are reversed from the expected values.

Comment: `curve_fit` takes an initial guess as a parameter (`p0`). By default, it's all ones.  If `a=1, b=1, c=1` is nowhere close to what a, b, and c are likely to be, then you'll need to supply something more reasonable.

Comment: Here is one of my datasets: http://pastebin.com/YfJXaNB9

Comment: Thanks! I have to run at the momment, but I'll take a look at it later tonight and see what I can do.

Comment: From graphing by hand in Excel I think the real parameters should be close to `p0 = numpy.asarray([0.45,-100,-.06])`, but when I plug those numbers I still get parameters output with the wrong sign, e.g. `[ -3.87491925e+01   3.22348002e+03  -1.06430736e+00]`. Also same errors `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power` and `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars`. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: From [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):
        The model function, f(x, ...).  It must take the independent
        variable as the first argument and the parameters to fit as
        separate remaining arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imports:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt
```

Sample values:

```
values = np.array('0.400    0.400   0.397   0.395   0.396   0.394   0.392   0.390   0.395   0.393   0.392   0.392   0.390   0.388   0.390   0.388   0.385   0.383   0.388   0.387   0.387   0.387   0.385   0.386   0.387   0.379   0.379   0.378   0.375   0.376   0.374   0.373   0.372   0.368   0.373   0.370   0.371   0.370   0.370   0.370   0.367   0.368   0.368   0.365   0.365   0.366   0.364   0.361   0.361   0.356   0.355   0.357   0.354   0.353   0.350   0.351   0.353   0.355   0.350   0.354   0.352   0.351   0.348   0.348   0.347   0.345   0.346   0.343   0.348   0.346   0.344   0.343   0.342   0.341   0.346   0.346   0.345   0.343   0.348   0.345   0.346   0.342   0.344   0.344   0.340   0.341   0.345   0.345   0.343   0.339   0.343   0.344   0.343   0.346   0.344   0.344   0.345   0.347   0.344   0.344   0.338   0.340   0.343   0.340   0.342   0.336   0.334   0.336   0.337   0.338   0.338   0.343   0.342   0.342   0.336   0.334   0.336   0.330   0.325   0.324   0.323   0.319   0.323   0.322   0.318   0.314   0.314   0.319   0.315   0.316   0.313   0.315   0.314   0.314   0.315   0.313   0.308   0.312   0.311   0.310   0.312   0.311'
                  ' 0.311   0.309   0.309   0.316   0.317   0.312   0.309   0.311   0.308   0.310   0.312'.split('\t'), dtype=float)
```

Old data preparation:

```
x=[]
y=[]
x_val = 0
for i in values: #values is a list of several thousand experimental data points
  if x_val < 100:
    x.append(float(x_val))
    y.append(float(i))
  x_val += 5
x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)
```

Easier data prep:

```
y1 = values[:100//5]
x1 = np.arange(len(y1))*5
```

Check it is the same:

```
print np.allclose(y, y1)
print np.allclose(x, x1)
```

Use numpy to define fit function:

```
def function(x, a,b,c):
    #a = upper asymptote
    #b = negative = x axis displacement
    #c = negative = growth rate
    return a*(np.exp(b*(np.exp(c*x))))
```

Fit using starting point p0:

```
pars, pcov = opt.curve_fit(function, x1, y1, p0=[0.1, -10, 0.1])
```

Draw:

```
yaj = function(x1, *pars)
plt.figure(1, figsize=(8.5, 11))
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'g-', x1, yaj, 'r-')
plt.xlim(min(x1), max(x1))
plt.ylim(min(y1), max(y1))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help! The issue was that I was defining function(a,b,c,x) whereas x must come first for curve_fit to work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in the comment :-)